# How to implement a currency converter as a block in a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal, module, converters, block, currency

I want to add a block in my Drupal site that contains a currency converter, similar to the converter at http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/

Any idea please ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with drupal or a 'block' - is it like a plugin where you can add it directly to your site? Obviously you can embed a link to yahoo or google so long as its not for commercial use.

Comment: Here is a simple solution:

Configuration > Text formats > Add text format : Give it a name e.g. 'Scripts', select the roles that can use it (I suggest restricting this to an admin type role only), and click save - dont check any of the filters.

Then add a new block, go on one of these links, and paste the widget code in the field "Block body" (choose 'Scripts' for the field "Text format"):
http://www.exchangerates.org.uk/webmasters/British-Pound-currency-conver...
http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&hl=en&gl=&q=currency://